# UIView Does Not Rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code in a UIViewController

```
Notepad *notepad = [[Notepad alloc] initForNewTopLevelTask:0 andDAO:self.dao];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:notepad animated:YES];
[notepad release];
```

The initForNewTopLevelTask:andDAO: method is:

```
- (id) initForNewTopLevelTask:(int) theTableSize andDAO:(DAO*) aDAO {
    self.dao = aDAO;
    tableSize = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:theTableSize];
    self.isNew = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    self.isSubtask =[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        return self;
}
```

When I rotate the view nothing happens, it does not rotate. If I change the UIViewController line to:

```
Notepad *notepad = [[Notepad alloc] init];
```

It rotates fine!

The view is not part of a Tab Controller and I have implemented:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always call up to a parent class init method in your own init methods.  Atleast for any object that is at some point extending from NSObject.

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4

Change your init function to:

```
- (id) initForNewTopLevelTask:(int) theTableSize andDAO:(DAO*) aDAO {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
    self.dao = aDAO;
    tableSize = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:theTableSize];
    self.isNew = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    self.isSubtask =[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```